# Amore Mio vs Tesoro Mio

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, idioms, phrase-choice

I'm trying to decide between inscribing a wedding band with either "Amore Mio" or "Tesoro Mio".

Doing some preliminary research on these two, it seems like "Amore Mio" is more romantic and would more likely be said between spouses. "Tesoro Mio" is also a term of endearment, but not necessarily romantic and could be used between friends, or parents and their children.

"Amore Mio" seems like a safer options, but I was initially leaning toward using "Tesoro Mio" because I think "Amore Mio" could come off as more generic/cliche. Additionally, calling someone your treasure by inscribing it on a literal piece of treasure seems more poetic to me than just calling them your love.

Does this poetic meaning properly translate over to Italian, or would calling someone "Tesoro Mio" have more of a "we're friends" vibe?

Which would be better for a wedding band inscription?

Comment: A particular reason why you need it in Italian? Is the other person Italian? In any case, no upper case for the second word: “Tesoro mio” or whatever.

Comment: We're both American, but with Italian heritage. We've started to learn the language together, visited the country together, and I know she'd enjoy it.

Comment: And I know that in normal writing the "mio" would not be capitalized, but in this situation, as a phrase inscribed on a ring, I think it might look better in Title Case rather than Sentence case. Not fully decided on this, but it's the direction I'm leaning.

Comment: I imagined that was the reasoning behind the upper case, but there is no such thing as “Title Case” in Italian. For instance, the title of Italo Calvino's novel _Il sentiero dei nidi di ragno_ is written like this, and having it as a _Il Sentiero Dei Nidi Di Ragno_ (give or take some capital letter) looks as bad as if it were actually misspellt.

Comment: @devjoco I think you can write what you prefer and what seems to you more appropriate. *Amore mio* is good, and *Tesoro mio* is good. It is true that *Amore* could be more solemn and *Tesoro* is more a term of endearment (as honey in English), but it doesn’t matter so much. *Tesoro* doesn’t imply that you are friends, and also *Amore* can be used between friends and parents and children. I I’ve a grocer who, when I enter the shop, calls me *amore*! It depends on customs.

Comment: As for capital letters, I agree with DaG, but I think you can do what you prefer: if you think that capital letters give more emphasis, use them, the important thing is how this writing  sounds to your wife and to you, and what are your feelings reading it.

Comment: Inside a ring, I would write *Amore mio*. *Tesoro* could be used when referring to a wife/husband, but I would not use that word in a wedding ring. As for writing *Mio* instead of *mio*, it could seems you are putting emphasis on *mio*, as to say *Amore soltanto mio e non di nessun'altro*.

Comment: Hmm a very good point @apaderno. That emphasis comes off as a weird/possessive thing to imply in my opinion. Was thinking titlecase for the overall visual balance of the words; leaning more towards "tesoro mio" or "amore mio" (all lowercase) now.